# In Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS), is the master component managed in an isolated environment from other users?

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-aks

In Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS), is the master component managed in an isolated environment from other users?
It is not possible to manipulate the resources of the AKS master component directly.
Therefore, I want to confirm that it is safe.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS), you can see a resource of the Kubernetes service when you create it. Also, you can find a resource group named MC_groupName_aksName_location associate to your aks. It means you can manage the resource of AKS in the Azure portal.  In addition, you can also remotely manage the resources use Azure CLI.

For the isolated environment, the AKS can be isolated from other users in the network level. For security, there is a Network Security Group for you. For more details about the security, see [Security concepts for applications and clusters in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-security).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The information about master I wanted was written in your shared document.

Comment: @Tsukuyomi If you feel like it, can you answer your own question then? It might help other users who run into this issue. It’s absolutely no problem if you mark your own answer as the solution of your question.